# seleccionar contenido campo input[type="search"]

Tags: html, jquery

Me gustaría que un campo type="search" se seleccione su contenido cuando se le hace click. Actualmente para cambiar un valor en un campo search debes hacer doble click para que se seleccione el valor que contiene el campo. Lo que necesito es  que haga lo mismo al tomar el foco o al hacer click.

```html
<label  class="col-md-1  control-label "  >Inicio:</label>
 <input type="text" " type="text"   class="form-control datepicker input-sm "  >
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para seleccionar el contenido tenes que usar la funcion `.select()` que suele funcionar bien con javascript nativo.

ejemplo utilizando jQuery con el fragmento de codigo que pasaste :

```js
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label  class="col-md-1  control-label "  >Inicio:</label>
 <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepicker input-sm "  >
```

espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: pero ahi no es JS nativo lo que usas, estas mezclandolo con JQuery conviene aclares eso

Answer (score 2):

Podés hacerlo con jQuery, de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#datepicker').on('click', function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Inicio:</label>
  <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control datepicker input-sm" value="Texto" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**with onclick="this.select()" **

```html
<label for="input"  class="col-md-1  control-label "  >Inicio:</label>
 <input id="input" type="text" " type="text"   class="form-control datepicker input-sm " value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" onclick="this.select()" >
```